# ML : match non-exhaustive

Tags: sml, ml, non-exhaustive-patterns

I want to make function named `headcol` that works like:

```
headcol[[1,2],[3,4]] = [1,3];
```

So i made function like this:

```
fun headcol [] = [] 
  | headcol [x::xs',y::ys'] = [x,y]
```

but when I call it, I get a match nonexhaustive.

Comment: *I want to make function named 'headcol'*, you should clarify what you want indeed. Your parameter is a list(which can have infinite elems), but you only math 2-elem list. That's what `nonexhaustive` means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `headcol` will extract all heads of lists in the parameter, whose type is `'a-list-list`. What you mathc is only `[]` and `[x::xs', y::ys']`, not anything else. So, if your argument has more than 2 sublists, execption will raise:

```
- headcol[[1,2],[3,4], [4, 5, 9]]; 

uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]
  raised at: a.sml:9.34
-
```

If you just want to deal with two-elems list, pair is a better choice. Otherwise, you should match more cases:

```
fun headcol list =
    case list of
        [] => []
      | x::xs' =>
        case x of
            [] => headcol xs'
         |  h::t => h::(headcol xs')
```

output:

```
- headcol[[1,2],[3,4], [4, 5, 9]]; 
- val it = [1,3,4] : int list
```

Comment: Could you rewrite the function using 'map'?

Comment: @이시온 Simon has given a thorough and perfect demo about `map`. If somewhere you don't understand, feel free to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

As 陳 力 points out, it is hard to answer a question defined only by the name of a function and its attempted solution. Still, `head` sounds like you want to take the first element of each sub-list, and `col` sounds like you're treating this list of lists as a matrix with columns being orthogonal to to the sub-lists.

The recursive solution might also look like:

```
fun headcol [] = []
  | headcol ((x::_)::xss) = x :: headcol xss
  | headcol ([]::xss) = headcol xss
```

Here is how you might do it using built-in higher-order list combinators:

```
fun headcol xss =
    List.concat (List.map (fn xs => List.take (xs, 1)) xss)
```

The reason why I'm not simply doing:

```
fun headcol xss =
    List.map hd xss
```

is because `hd` is a partial function, so `hd []` will crash at run-time.

On the other hand, `List.take ([], 1)` will return `[]`.

And `List.concat` will combine the temporary result `[[1],[2],[3]]` into `[1,2,3]`.

Or, in case a column is missing, `[[1],[],[3]]` into `[1,3]`.

Test cases:

```
val test_headcol_0 = headcol [] = []
val test_headcol_1 = headcol [[1]] = [1]
val test_headcol_2 = headcol [[1,2],[3,4]] = [1,3]
val test_headcol_3 = headcol [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] = [1,4,7]
val test_headcol_4 = headcol [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]] = [1,2,4]
val test_headcol_5 = headcol [[1],[],[2,3]] = [1,2]
```

Of course, I don't know if that's the behavior you expect from `headcol` with regards to irregular matrices that don't have a head column. This is a corner case you don't go into. In functional programming, you often embed error handling into the return value rather than throw exceptions.

So for example, you could want from `headcol` to return an `'a list option` where `SOME [1,4,7]` suggests that each row did have a head column, and `NONE` suggests that at least one row failed to produce a column.

Or you could use a data type other than `'a list list` to represent your matrix that does not allow rows with missing columns, e.g. an [Array2](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array2.html#ARRAY2:SIG:SPEC).